# Problems adjustbox moves to another subsection

Tags: tables, adjustbox

I have difficulties with adjustbox. I had created a subsection and inside it is a table and this table moves to another subsection and I do not know how to fix this problem. I hope your help, please:

use

```
\documentclass[14pt,a4paper]{extarticle}
```

example of subsection

```
\subsection{Operacionalización de Variables}

\begin{quote}

\begin{table}[]
\begin{adjustbox}{max width=\textwidth}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|c|l|c|}
\hline
\textbf{Variable} & \textbf{Dimension} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textbf{Indicador}} & \textbf{Sub Indicador} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textbf{Escala de Medición}} \\ \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Factores \\ Demográficos\end{tabular}} & Sexo & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Hombre      \\ Mujer\end{tabular} &  & Nominal \\ \cline{2-5} 
 & Lugar de residencia & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}zona urbana  \\ zona urbana marginal\\ zona marginal\end{tabular} &  & Nominal \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Factores \\ Economicos\end{tabular}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Condición económica} & Ingresos & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}\textless{}1000\\ 1001 -1200\\ 1200 -1300\\ 1300 -1600\\ \textgreater{}1600\end{tabular}} & Ordinal \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{adjustbox}
\end{table}

 \end{quote}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Why do you use `\begin{table}...\end{table}`? This will make the box with the tabular float around to where ever TeX thinks there is enough space.

Comment: he had used this page  https://www.tablesgenerator.com  and I copied the result, did I delete the `\begin {table}` ?

Comment: Remove `\begin{table}...`\end{table}` and replace `\textwidth` by `\linewidth`. Note that parts of your page may stay blank if the table doesn't fit at this point. Moreover, using `\begin{quote}...\end{quote}` reduces the width available for the tabular.

Answer (score 2):

You might also look at the needspace package.  This is easier to show than explain.

```
\documentclass[14pt,a4paper]{extarticle}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{needspace}

\newsavebox{\tempbox}% just in case

\begin{document}
\setcounter{section}{2}
\setcounter{subsection}{8}
\rule{1pt}{25\baselineskip}% threshold for new page

\setbox\tempbox=\vbox{%
\subsection{Operacionalización de Variables}

\begin{adjustbox}{max width=\textwidth}
\begin{tabular}[b]{|l|l|c|l|c|}
\hline
\textbf{Variable} & \textbf{Dimension} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textbf{Indicador}} & \textbf{Sub Indicador} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textbf{Escala de Medición}} \\ \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Factores \\ Demográficos\end{tabular}} & Sexo & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Hombre      \\ Mujer\end{tabular} &  & Nominal \\ \cline{2-5} 
 & Lugar de residencia & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}zona urbana  \\ zona urbana marginal\\ zona marginal\end{tabular} &  & Nominal \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Factores \\ Economicos\end{tabular}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Condición económica} & Ingresos & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}\textless{}1000\\ 1001 -1200\\ 1200 -1300\\ 1300 -1600\\ \textgreater{}1600\end{tabular}} & Ordinal \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{adjustbox}}

\needspace{\ht\tempbox}\unvbox\tempbox

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your table (i.e. the `tabular`) is wrapped in a `table` environment which is a so called 'float', i.e. it floats through the text and is placed on a suitable position, mostly on a page boundary. There are ways to change this (see e.g. [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39017/how-to-influence-the-position-of-float-environments-like-figure-and-table-in-lat)) but in your case it might be better to force a non-floating table. The `adjustbox` package helps you here, just use the `nofloat=table` key. If you need extra vertical space (as replacement for the `quote` environment) then also add the `vspace=<amount>` key.

```
\documentclass[14pt,a4paper]{extarticle}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}
\blindtext

\subsection{Operacionalización de Variables}
\begin{adjustbox}{max width=\textwidth,nofloat=table,vspace=\medskipamount}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|c|l|c|}
\hline
\textbf{Variable} & \textbf{Dimension} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textbf{Indicador}} & \textbf{Sub Indicador} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textbf{Escala de Medición}} \\ \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Factores \\ Demográficos\end{tabular}} & Sexo & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Hombre      \\ Mujer\end{tabular} &  & Nominal \\ \cline{2-5} 
 & Lugar de residencia & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}zona urbana  \\ zona urbana marginal\\ zona marginal\end{tabular} &  & Nominal \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Factores \\ Economicos\end{tabular}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Condición económica} & Ingresos & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}\textless{}1000\\ 1001 -1200\\ 1200 -1300\\ 1300 -1600\\ \textgreater{}1600\end{tabular}} & Ordinal \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{adjustbox}

\blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image]